# Which algorithm is used by LSODA in solve_ivp to generate the dense_output?

Tags: python, scipy

I have checked the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html). The interpolation techniques used by various methods are mentioned for say, RK45, Radau, etc. but it is silent on what is used for LSODA and BDF. I will be grateful for an answer.

Comment: I see references for those methods.  Also a Fortran ODEPAC mention.

Comment: Yes but I don't think those refs have the answer. I don't think generating an interpolating function (i.e., the dense output) was/is a part of the old FORTRAN codes. For example, odeint is based on LSODA but it does not have an option for generating a dense output.

Comment: We'd have dig into the code more, but it looks like the dense `sol` is generated from the solution afterwards.  It doesn't depend on the method.

Comment: Hmm. I found this but it is not very illuminating https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.LSODA.dense_output.html#scipy.integrate.LSODA.dense_output

Comment: It is implemented here:  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/91a279ecb05e7814e2787bfa618d46ad3e0af2be/scipy/integrate/_ivp/lsoda.py#L163-L188  You would have to cross reference these equations with those in LSODA